# Black Screen in Zoom

Tags: updates, zoom-meeting

Occuring the **black screen** while sharing the screen in ZOOM.

I've recently upgraded my ubuntu version 22.04

Answer (score 1):

You can't share your desktop in Zoom using `wayland`.

You can select X.org instead of `wayland` when log in the system.